How to fix the stuttering and unstable connection with Sony WH-1000XM5 Bluetooth headphones on Kubuntu 24.04?
My bluetooth headset WH-1000XM5 works well and stable on Windows 11, android, Ubuntu 22.04 Dell laptop. I just dualbooted my laptop with Kubuntu 24.04. I have a hard time connecting the headset and when I leave it alone it will connect automatically, but the audio stutters and it feels like the connection is very unstable. Sometimes it disconnects and reconnects automatically.
I tried setting the playbackmode on Headset Head Unit, then the connection is stable, but the audio quality is poor.

Logs from journalctl -u bluetooth.
It disconnected and reconnected around 21:49:32
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
nov 01 18:34:43 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[1159]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
nov 02 21:28:51 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.178 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
nov 02 21:29:20 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Close: Connection timed out (110)
nov 02 21:29:22 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Abort: Connection timed out (110)
nov 02 21:30:24 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: src/device.c:search_cb() 88:C9:E8:3A:BC:79: error updating services: Input/output error (5)
nov 02 21:30:24 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
nov 02 21:30:30 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_C9_E8_3A_BC_79/sep3/fd2: fd(39) ready
nov 02 21:31:32 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_C9_E8_3A_BC_79/sep1/fd3: fd(39) ready
nov 02 21:31:47 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_C9_E8_3A_BC_79/sep1/fd4: fd(39) ready
nov 02 21:31:57 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_C9_E8_3A_BC_79/sep3/fd5: fd(39) ready
nov 02 21:49:32 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
nov 02 21:49:40 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
nov 02 21:49:50 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
nov 02 21:49:56 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:load_remote_sep() Unable to load LastUsed: rseid 3 not found
nov 02 21:49:58 TUFkubuntu bluetoothd[36140]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_C9_E8_3A_BC_79/sep3/fd6: fd(42) ready

Laptop specs
ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA507RR
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with Radeon Graphics
RAM: 16GB DDR5
GPU: Nvidia RTX 3070 (nvidia-driver-550)

edit, I got it fixed for now

By turning the laptop completely off instead of rebooting
By switching to Windows, I feel like you have to remove the laptop with the android app (Sound Connect) in the paired devices, and do the pairing again
I changed Sound Quality Mode in Sound Connect from Prioritize Sound Quality to Priority on Stable Connection


have you tried to install the correct drivers for that specific headset? Or just changing the Bluetooth driver? That should do the trick.
